# Populate text with PHP Session information

Tags: php, session

I have a page where, after a user logs in, the session starts and there is a welcome message with the User's Name - like so:

```
<h2>Welcome, <?php echo $_SESSION["User"]; ?>, to the site!</h2>
```

Or something along those lines - haven't decided, yet.
But the problem is, is that it doesn't show up.

I have the code that authenticates the user and all that, and that portion works.
They authenticate and they have a session - it DOES exist (if not, the page would redirect them to the login or the error page depending on how many tries).

When they authenticate, the form posts to a "login.php" where all the other code happens, including this:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit']) && ($allowEntry == yes))
{
 session_start();
 session_register ("Logged_In");
 session_register("User");
 $_SESSION["Logged_In"] = 'true';
 $_SESSION["User"] = $user;

if ($_SESSION["User"]=='SOMEUSER')
{
header( 'Location: /somepage.php' );

exit;
}
elseif ($_SESSION["User"]=='SOMEOTHERUSER')
{
header( 'Location: /someOtherPage.php' );
exit;
}
}
```

So, does anyone know how to make that text appear in the "" element above?

Comment: Huh what? In the "" element? I dont get it?

Comment: I'm going to take a wild guess that you forgot session_start on the other page.

Comment: That was the issue, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I completely understand the question, but I gather that you're setting the session in one script and trying to obtain a value from it in another? If so, it's most likely because you haven't called [`session_start()`](https://www.php.net/session_start) in the second. Note from the docs

> session_start() creates a session or resumes the current one based on
> a session identifier passed via a GET or POST request, or passed via a
> cookie.

Comment: THAT was the problem!  Thanks all!  I appreciate it!  Much Love for the Stack Overflow folks!